# Need some help on some reactjs logic

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Header` component used in multiple React pages, in `props` I have the `user.name` stored, and will display it if the user is logged in. The problem is that, the `user.name` will only exist after the user login, and I can't figure out how to handle it before the user login.
Here is some critical part of my code:

```
class Header extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated, name } = this.props;
        ...
        return (
            ...
            {isAuthenticated && (
                ...
                <sometag>
                    {name}
                </sometag>
                ...
            )}
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    name: state.user.name
});
```

I have it tested before the login cache expires, everything is ok. But when login again my code breaks @:

```
name: state.user.name
```

Because the `user` does not exist yet, so by access `user.name` is actually accessing `null.name`.

How can I solve this? Maybe something like `if (isAuthenticated)` for the `name` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming error is because of below snippet

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    name: state.user.name
});
```

you can do it:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    name: state.user&&state.user.name?state.user.name:""
});
```